# How to get the fragment Id from the clicked view or how to identify which part is clicked in from one of 4parts(divide screen into 4 equal parts)?

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I have to design an application for tablet. Due to the fact that space availability in that, I have decided to use fragment. Have to split the screen into four parts. Each part displays news title and description. When I click any one part from that 4 part, I have to get the corresponding fragment ID. How can I get it.

In my layout I have given frame layout, and added fragment dynamically using the fragment manager.

> ```
> ralativLayout_Id.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>   public void onClick(View v) {    
>       ///Here I need to get the clicked part's fragment ID. Or have to find out  which part clicked using any way.
>       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked " + news_title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                  
>       ///Have to show the selected news in the whole screen need to call another activity for that.           }
> });
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have to design an application for tablet. Due to the fact that space
>   availability in that, I have decided to use fragment. Have to split
>   the screen into four parts. Each part displays news title and
>   description. When I click any one part from that 4 part, I have to get
>   the corresponding fragment ID. How can I get it.

You have the option of attaching an extra piece of information to an Android `View` using the `setTag()` method(and retrieve it with `getTag()`). So in your fragments you can do:

```
// set as the tag for the view the Fragment's id
ralativLayout_Id.setTag(getId());
ralativLayout_Id.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) { 
      //retrieve the fragment's id   
      Integer fragmentId = (Integer) v.getTag();
      // now you have the fragment's id
      ///Here I need to get the clicked part's fragment ID. Or have to find out  which part clicked using any way.
      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked " + news_title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                  
      ///Have to show the selected news in the whole screen need to call another activity for that.           }
});
```

Comment: Really a nice... It solves my problem. Hopes helps some one. And I have one more doubt. Now I am calling another activity with the frame layout. And in that framelayout am goin to add the clicked fragment. How can I accomplish this. Because its already added. So how can I add the clicked fragment to the layout view.

Comment: @MVignesh I'm not sure I understand. If you want to call a new `Activity` in the `OnClickListener` and move that particular `Fragment` in the new `Activity` you can't do this(and you shouldn't in the first place). Instead just pass in the `Intent` the `Fragment`'s `id`(and any additional data that you might have) and construct a new `Fragment` based on that id in the new `Activity`. If this isn't what you look for please explain better what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MVignesh I was referring that you should start the `NewsDetailsActivity` and in its `onCreate` method create the desired `Fragment`(`NewsFragment`). And you cant pass the id in the `Intent` if you need it.

Comment: Ya I can get the fragment object like   NewsFragment clickedFragment = (NewsFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(fragmentId); Then in the new activity I am getting that fragment object like   NewsFragment clickedFragment = GlobalValues.getClicked_fragment_obj();
Now am wannna to add this to my new activity's layout. How to achieve this.

Comment: @MVignesh Please read what I said again. You **don't send** the fragment that is currently in the `Activity` to the new `Activity` that you create(you send its data so you recreate it). This would be wrong and with potential for many errors/exception.

Comment: Ya ya got ur point... So I have to pass that fragment data only... From the new activity I have to construct a new fragment from the dats brought from the old activity. Thanks for your valuable reply.

Comment: One more doubt in that. I have added four fragment to fragments transaction. And I have committed that. A single screen with four parts(Four Fragments). Now I have to implement view pager in that. How can I achieve that. Using that view pager library I have to pass the fragment manager and fragmentlist as argument. In  my scenario How can I pass every 4 argument in a single time?

Comment: @MVignesh Please ask a new question providing the relative details(how you setup the fragments, the ViewPager etc), we can't continue discussing in the comments area for this question.